# Convert JSON string into object in casperJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I have  JSON string in the form

```
  [
    {
        "couponcode": "HOMEV300JF",
        "source": "a",
        "description": "Rs 300 OFF on Home and Furniture section, on a minimum purchase of 1499 and above. Applicable on products..."
    },
    {
        "couponcode": "MENSP10PMA",
        "source": "a",
        "description": "Upto 50% off + Add 10% off on Rs.999"
    },
    {
        "couponcode": "MOVIE1000",
        "source": "a",
        "description": "Shop For Rs. 1999 & Above & Get 4 Movie Tickets Free Worth Rs. 1000 For Free"
    },
    {
        "couponcode": "SALE15",
        "source": "a",
        "description": "Get upto 75% off + Additional 15% off on Rs.2499"
    },
    {
        "couponcode": "SALE25",
        "source": "a",
        "description": "Get upto 75% off + Additional 25% off on Rs.2499"
    }
]
```

I want to convert this JSON (casperJS) into an object so that i can access it like an object as

`var length = object.length`

Comment: `JSON.parse()`, and you have an Array, not a plain object.

Comment: @Brad I tried JSON.parse() . but its not giving me the result

Comment: Yes it is.  http://jsfiddle.net/tJcbH/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: Then the JSON is either invalid, different than you think it is or what you are trying to do is not possible. If you post your code, you might get better help.

Comment: @Brad I was doing some mistake. Thanks for the fiddle. It worked like charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Brad is correct, and here's your (slightly modified version of his) answer:

```
var TempName = JSON.parse('[{"couponcode": "HOMEV300JF", "source": "a", "description": "Rs 300 OFF on Home and Furniture section, on a minimum purchase of 1499 and above. Applicable on products..."}, {"couponcode": "MENSP10PMA", "source": "a", "description": "Upto 50% off + Add 10% off on Rs.999"}, {"couponcode": "MOVIE1000", "source": "a", "description": "Shop For Rs. 1999 & Above & Get 4 Movie Tickets Free Worth Rs. 1000 For Free"}, {"couponcode": "SALE15", "source": "a", "description": "Get upto 75% off + Additional 15% off on Rs.2499"}, {"couponcode": "SALE25", "source": "a", "description": "Get upto 75% off + Additional 25% off on Rs.2499"}]');

var length = TempName.length;

console.log(length); // see it...
```